# Confused by strace output of a simple helloworld nasm program

Tags: assembly, system-calls, strace

I found a small helloworld nasm program at [this page](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/hello-world-nasm-assembler).

It can be *compiled/linkd/run* easily on my Debian without any problem. The source code is copied at the end of this post.

```
> # Compile
> nasm -f elf64 hello.asm -o hello.o
> # Link
> ld hello.o -o hello
> # Run
> ./hello
```

But when I did *strace* on it, the output confused me.

```
> ## output of 'strace ./hello' ##
>
> execve("./hello", ["./hello"], 0x7ffc9dadd930 /* 89 vars */) = 0
> stat(NULL, Hello, world!
> NULL)                        = 14
> write(0, NULL, 14)                      = ?
> +++ exited with 0 +++
>
> ## end of output ##
```

What I can't understand:

1. the *write()* line looks strange to me. Shouldn't it be like:

   ```
   write(1, "hello, world!", 14) = 14
   ```

   Why it writes to file descriptor 0(STDIN) instead of 1(STDOUT)? And 
   if I *strace* another similar hello compiled from a hello.c, I did 
   find a line that expected:

   ```
   write(1, "hello\n", 6hello) = 6
   ```

   So, what's wrong with the nasm program, or maybe strace?
2. The return value of stat() is 14. Is it the string length, or an error number?

The source code of hello.asm is copied here:

```
; Define variables in the data section
SECTION .DATA
    hello:     db 'Hello world!',10
    helloLen:  equ $-hello

; Code goes in the text section
SECTION .TEXT
    GLOBAL _start 

_start:
    mov eax,4            ; 'write' system call = 4
    mov ebx,1            ; file descriptor 1 = STDOUT
    mov ecx,hello        ; string to write
    mov edx,helloLen     ; length of string to write
    int 80h              ; call the kernel

    ; Terminate program
    mov eax,1            ; 'exit' system call
    mov ebx,0            ; exit with error code 0
    int 80h              ; call the kernel
```

Comment: You might want to use [proper 64-bit system calls instead](https://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the legacy syscall interface. Use `syscall` instead.

According to this ["bug report"](https://github.com/strace/strace/issues/103), strace before 4.26 doesn't correctly trace that interface.
It requires a 5.3 or linux-next kernel.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute and trace 32bit program with legacy calling convention (INT 0x80) on 64bit system, assemble and link it as 32bit:

```
; # Compile
; nasm -f elf hello.asm -o hello.o
; # Link
; ld hello.o -o hello -m elf_i386
; # Run
; ./hello
; # Trace
; strace ./hello

> ld hello.o -o hello -m elf_i386
> ./hello
Hello world!
> strace ./hello
execve("./hello", ["./hello"], [/* 57 vars */]) = 0
[ Process PID=15247 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
write(1, "Hello world!\n", 13Hello world!)          = 13
_exit(0)                                = ?
>
```